# How to filter NSDictionary by substring in its keys?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

Say I have an `NSDictionary` and its keys are like this:

1. `@"123_000"`
2. `@"223_000"`
3. `@"123_111"`
4. `@"223_111"`

and so on. I want to get a `NSArray` or `NSSet` of all values whose corresponding keys contain substring `@"123"`.

Of course I can just loop over the `NSDictionary`, but I suspect that there must be a less code heavy approach, probably involving `KVC` or `NSPredicate`, but I'm not really good in either of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `NSPredicate`.

First get `allKeys` from the dictionary. Then use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` to get the list of keys you want. Then use `objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:` with your resulting array of keys to get the associated objects (the not found marker isn't an issue as we know all keys exist).

Answer (score 1):

To correct the answer of VaaChar:

In my example, I have a dictionary with keys and values only (vegan : 1, steak : 2, ...)

To check if my string is within these keys, I use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@", keyword];
NSArray *categories     = [[self.categoriesAndIDs allKeys] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

SELF represents the current object of the given array, in my case [self.categoriesAndIDs allKeys] so every string within the array will be checked for my "keyword", e.g. "steak" or "st" and the result will be an array with a string called "steak".

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this:

```
NSArray *resultArray = [[mainDict allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.@allKeys CONTAINS[c] %@", @"123"]];
```

"self.@allKeys" should return all keys of your dictionary and "CONTAINS[c] %@" checks if the key contains "123".

Comment: Did you try this? As far as I can see this just doesn't work. Did you mistype or miss something out of your answer?